# Decoding Error: typeMismatch - Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but found a string/data instead

Tags: swift, codable

Got this API response:

```
...
"campaigns": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": {
                    "en": "Example Campaign",
                    "de": "Beispiel Kampagne"
                },
                "targetagegroup": null,
                ...
```

I'm decoding into:

```swift
class Campaign: Codable {

    var id: Int?
    var name: [String:String]?
    var targetagegroup: String?
    ...
}
```

All works fine.
But with this response:

```
...
 "someproperty": null,
 "slogan": {
     "en": "foo",
     "de": "bar"
 },
 "someotherproperty": null,
 ...
```

When decoding into:

```swift
class User: Codable {
 ...
 var someproperty: String?
 var slogan: [String:String]?
 var someotherproperty: String?
 ...
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "detailresponse", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "element", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "participants", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "slogan", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Not sure why decoding a User gives me issues with when decoding a Campaign doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not receive the slogan property as a plain JSON string instead of an object ?

Comment: You seem to have elided much of the relevant information that likely makes Campaign and User different in your real code, but identical here. Build a playground that demonstrates the problem in a way that you can post and we can reproduce it. (In many cases, building that example will show you the problem anyway.)

Comment: @RobNapier: I've abstracted it because everything works just fine if I comment out `var slogan: [String:String]?` in class User. So I've concluded that the rest should not be relevant. Would you agree?

Comment: @jtouzy: I'm receiving it exactly as it's shown above. Copy and paste from the response.

Comment: @BernhardEngl how did you watch the network response ? With Charles Proxy or just a simple print ? Some tools may alter the received result.

Comment: @jtouzy: I've used PostMan

Comment: Please show the **entire** error message. Most likely in one of the items in the array `slogan` is a string rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Maybe make some screenshot about postman **raw** response to analyze it.

Comment: The code and data you've given us work fine. See: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/832bc5dffd9e2e08930721783bd2e40f. You have cut out some piece of important information. Please make an example that looks like my gist, but shows the problem.

Comment: @jtouzy: here's postman raw: `"slogan":{"en":"foo","de":"bar"},`

Comment: @vadian: did as you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says

> The value for key `slogan`
>   at index 1 of array `participants`
>                 at index 0 of array `element`
>                 in `detailresponse`

is a string rather than the expected dictionary.

Please check the JSON

Comment: I understandt that. But this here `"slogan": {
            "en": "foo",
            "de": "bar"
        },` is copy paste from the response. So I don't understand why that would be a string. That's a dictionary.

Comment: Check the whole (coding) path. Index 0 is the first item and index 1 is the second item. Actually if the decoder throws an error then there is a string.

Comment: Many thanks!!! You were right. `slogan` for the second `participant` was indeed a string - and I was looking at the first `participant`...

Answer (score 1):

Your second object doesn't appear to be valid JSON.

```
{
    "someproperty": null,
    "slogan": {
        "en": "foo",
        "de": "bar"
    },
    "someotherproperty": null,
}
```

That decodes for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, i think you receive a plain string into your "slogan" property in your JSON result. And not an object like you describe.

I tried in a playground :

```swift
struct Campain: Codable {
    var slogan: [String:String]?
}

let json = "{\"slogan\": \"\"}"
let campain = JSONDecoder().decode(Campain.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(campain)
```

Gives me the error :

```
DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      ▿ codingPath : 1 element
        - 0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "slogan", intValue: nil)
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but found a string/data instead."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

If i put a real object in the JSON (same as your example), it works.